# deleting node_modules, get error EPERM operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Recently started to get this error:

```
AppData\Roaming\nvm\v9.5.0\node_modules\rimraf\bin.js:47
      throw er
      ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\users\matt\sites\rg-calendar\node_modules'
```

I have tried running cmd prompt in administrator and disabled my antivirus.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to kill your `Node.js` process completely.

Todo so follow the below steps,

1. Goto the **Task Manager** (Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>)
2. Under the "**Processes**" search for the process named "**Node.js:Server-side- 
   JavaScript**"
3. Right click that and click on "**Go to details**"
4. You will get navigated to the "**Details**" tab with the node process selected.
   Right click that and select "**End Process tree**".
5. Once done, Try deleting your **node_modules** directory again.

If the above steps are not working for you try installing the `rimraf` package by using, `npm install rimraf -g` and then try deleting your `node_modules` directory with it. (like this =>) `rimraf node_modules`

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Node.js isnt running as a process, is there a way I can find out which process is causing the problem?

Comment: @Bomber In that case, Try installing `rimraf` package by issuing `npm install rimraf -g` command and then try executing `rimraf node_modules` which will do the trick for you.

Comment: Okay, Can you please go into your `node_modules` directory and try deleting all the directories residing there and once everything is deleted, try deleting the `node_modules` directory.